# WPF XAML Global Reference

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Is there a way to reuse a 3rd party control reference?

For example, I have this referenced in my App.xaml

```
xmlns:cust="clr-namespace:ThirdParty.Controls;assembly=ThirdParty.Controls"
```

I don't want to repeat this 3rd party control xml namespace on each page/control that needs a control from the library.

Is there anyway to centralize these references and use the prefix defined here? The possibility of each control having a different prefix is also worrisome.  In asp.net you would put a reference in the web.config and it was available globally, I'm just looking to see if there is a similar method in WPF.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two options I am thinking

1) Wrap that control into a UserControl and then use your UserControl in all the places.

2) Declare the third party control as a Resource somewhere and then use DynamicResource reference to that on your other places.

The second option can be implemented as bellow.

Where ever you want the third party control put a ContentControl like bellow

```
<ContentControl Template="{DynamicResource thirdPartyControlTemplate}" />
```

The ControlTemplate will be in the Resource file or at App.Xaml as bellow.

```
  xmlns:thridParty="clr-namespace:WpfCustomControlLibrary1;assembly=WpfCustomControlLibrary1"                >
<Application.Resources>
    <ControlTemplate x:Key="thirdPartyControlTemplate" TargetType="{x:Type ContentControl}">
        <thridParty:ThirdPartyControl />
    </ControlTemplate>
</Application.Resources>
```

You can see that the namespace declaration will be always on this resource file and you will be able to use that Control control from any place

Comment: Thanks, this is the closest I can get to a global include.  Though I'll probably just ignore the includes on every window and deal with it.

Answer (score 0):

Take an example from the built-in control template for a Label:

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="Label" 
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
    xmlns:s="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib" 
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
```

[Show Me The Template](http://www.sellsbrothers.com/tools/#ShowMeTheTemplate) is an amazingly helpful resource for these kinds of things. HTH

Comment: I'm not sure how this would help.  I don't want to change the template of the 3rd party control, I want to reference the same control from a central xmlns import.  If this buys me that somehow, please explain in more detail.

Comment: Ah, I misread your question. I thought you had a user or custom control that required a 3rd party library. Really what you're looking for is a way to do a global include in XAML.

Comment: Yeah, sad there isn't a solution.  It's not an issue doing something in Blend as it does it all for you, but visual studio is lacking.